# Как узнать насколько растягивается TextureView?

Tags: java, android

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда я работаю с превью камеры, то у меня почему то в нижней части экрана появляется белая полоса, как показано на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала было предположение, что это высота место для программных кнопок управления (домой, назад, меню) для устройств, где нет аппаратных кнопок при чем она может быть либо `168px` либо `96px` - в зависимости от экрана.

Но как видим, что программные кнопки на скриншоте и так есть значит это место точно не под них...

мне кажется причина в том, что для вывода картинки с камеры на экран я использую `AutoFitTextureView` который автоматически подбирает наилучшие размеры и соотношение сторон для себя и когда размеры динамически посчитаны то в него устанавливается превью (картинка) с камеры... И вот я думаю, что вся проблема в том, что `AutoFitTextureView` при разрешении экрана `2550 * 1280` оно просто не может равномерно растянуться на всю площадь сохраняя правильное соотношение сторон... Как вы считаете? Может это быть правильным? Не знаю как это проверить правда...

Вся проблема в том, что я хочу наложить цвет на эту белую полосу, чтоб нормально смотрелось, и когда я накладываю цвет на экране с разрешением `1920х1080` все красиво смотрится, но когда тоже самое загружаю на устройство `2560х1080` , то `AutoFitTextureView` не дотягивает до нижней части экрана еще больше чем на экране с меньшим разрешением и получается что белая полоса торчит над цветом который статично занимает у меня 96 пикселей.

**Не знаю может это частично вопрос к дизайнерам, но как решить такую проблему когда на разных экранах `AutoFitTextureView` тянется по разному и на одном экране белой полосы нет, на другом 100 пикселей ее ширина, а на третьем 200??**

Вот XML файл

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView>
```

и вот на всякий случай java класс

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be measured based on the ratio
     * calculated from the parameters. Note that the actual sizes of parameters don't matter, that
     * is, calling setAspectRatio(2, 3) and setAspectRatio(4, 6) make the same result.
     *
     * @param width  Relative horizontal size
     * @param height Relative vertical size
     */
    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы неверно поняли, о чем я говорил. Вы спрашивали, почему физическая высота устройства равна 2560px, а при запросе у системы этой высоты из приложения в некоторых случаях она меньше - тогда и отнимается высота виртуальных кнопок управления, если они присутствуют, так как приложению эта область недоступна (при этом они занимают все "потерянное" место, а ее высота определяется в `dp`, поэтому в пикселях она разная и не обязательно 196px или 96px). В этом вопросе очевидно, что пропорции изображения не позволяют уместить его целиком на экран без искажения - виртуальные кнопки тут ни причем.

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, как то я не так выразился... Но в целом спасибо! Скажите есть ли у вас предположения по решению этого вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем хардкодить полоску, задай бэкграунд нужного цвета у лэйаута

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю стоит попробовать так:

```
<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView>
```

Comment: нет конечно, так не будет работать.